# Visual studio postbuild event xcopy and checkout files

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, xcopy, post-build-event

I'm using Post build event in Visual Studio to copy some .js files from a project to another using xcopy. I'm even using the \r option to overwrite any existing files. That has been achieved! It's copies the desired files to the destination directory, overwriting the existing files, but the problem is, despite changing the 'destination' files, doesn't check them out in TFS.

Is there a solution for checking out the 'destination' files automatically so I can be able to check in the correct version of those files to the server?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TF.exe command to checkout the files on the commandline:

```
c:\pi>tf checkout /type:text page.xsl
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yft8zkw(v=vs.100).aspx